# Associative Arrays Calculation

Tags: php

I have result array like this (below).

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [iPlannedCourseId] => 56
                    [fCreditHours] => 15.25
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [iPlannedCourseId] => 57
                    [fCreditHours] => 14.50
                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [iPlannedCourseId] => 58
                    [fCreditHours] => 12.25
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [iPlannedCourseId] => 59
                    [fCreditHours] => 14.75
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [iPlannedCourseId] => 60
                    [fCreditHours] => 15.25
                )

        )

)
```

I want summing of fCreditHours as per Parent Key. Is there any function without use of looping
i.e.,

```
Array 
(
        [10] = > 29.75
        [11] = > 42.25
)
```

Comment: So what have you actually tried... have you looked at looping the array? We'll help you with coding problems, but not write it for you

Comment: Looping is going to be the easiest way without specifically calling each element of the array

Answer (score 0):

you can try with array_walk() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try with array_walk_recursive and array_map combination.

I think this is useful to you :

```
$a = array(100,300,
                    array(
                        2,
                        4,
                        ),
                        array(
                        13,
                        80,
                        ),
                        array(
                        40,
                50,
                        ),2.2,420,                        
                );


 $max = 0;

array_walk_recursive($a, 'arrmax');
function arrmax($item, $key) {
   global $max;
   $max = ($item > $max) ? $item : $max;

}
echo "Maximum Value is : " . $max;
```